# How to move files of same extension in databricks files system?

Tags: databricks

I am facing file not found exception when i am trying to move the file with * in DBFS. Here both source and destination directories are in DBFS. I have the source file named "test_sample.csv" available in dbfs directory and i am using the command like below from notebook cell,

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/usr/krishna/sample/test*.csv", "dbfs:/user/abc/Test/Test.csv")
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbfs:/usr/krishna/sample/test*.csv
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Wildcards are currently not supported with dbutils.
You can move the whole directory:

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/tmp/test", "dbfs:/tmp/test2", recurse=True)
```

or just a single file:

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/tmp/test/test.csv", "dbfs:/tmp/test2/test2.csv")
```

As mentioned in the comments below, you can use python to implement this wildcard-logic. See also some code examples in my following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028526/9678762).

Comment: I must use wild card in my case since there are so many files which are not needed in the same directory. I need to move only csv  file in that directory. Meanwhile i have found some workaround in my pyspark code.
    fileList = dbutils.fs.ls(dir)
    for files in fileList: if files.name.endswith("csv"): filename= files.path
filename
dbutils.fa.mv(filename,'<dbfs_path>').

Comment: Use a for loop; listdir and move all of them at a time. Are wildcards still not allowed?

Comment: Note for R users: when using 'recurse=True' the 'True' must be capitalised ie recurse=TRUE

Answer (score 5):

Since the wildcards are not allowed, we need to make it work in this way (list the files and then move or copy - slight traditional way)

```
import os

def db_list_files(file_path, file_prefix):
  file_list = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls(file_path) if os.path.basename(file.path).startswith(file_prefix)]
  return file_list

files = db_list_files('dbfs:/your/src_dir', 'foobar')

for file in files:
  dbutils.fs.cp(file, os.path.join('dbfs:/your/tgt_dir', os.path.basename(file)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code in a Databricks cluster, you could access DBFS using the nodes file system. I'm not sure if in the background it requests all the objects and then filters, but at least you can use wildcards. E.g. from a databricks notebook

```
%sh
ls /dbfs/cluster-logs/*/driver/log4j-2021-09-01*
```

Comment: This works but it takes almost 2 mins to fetch records for particular date.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbutils.fs.mv("file:/<source>", "dbfs:/<destination>", recurse=True)
```

Use the above command to move a local folder to dbfs.