# Remove folder in blob in a more effective way

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

Suppose I am going to remove a folder from the blob from databricks using `dbutils.fs.rm("wabs://..../folder")`

However when the folder is not empty, it throws the error "non-empty" directory is not permitted.

Even has error include recurse=True

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001HKHXJCA5/how-to-delete-a-folder-in-databricks-mnt), the below function helps me solve this problem.

```py
def delete_mounted_dir(dirname):
    files=dbutils.fs.ls(dirname)
    for f in files:
        if f.isDir():
            delete_mounted_dir(f.path)
        dbutils.fs.rm(f.path, recurse=True)
    # delete the folder itself
    dbutils.fs.rm(dirname, recurse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Delete the file or directory (optionally recursively delete all files in the directory). This call throws an exception with IO_ERROR if the path is a non-empty directory and recursive is set to false or on other similar errors.

[image]

For more details, refer similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091812/remove-files-from-directory-after-uploading-in-databricks-using-dbutils) thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so rm a directory recusively is not permitted on non-empty directory ?

Comment: The rm function receives 2 parameters :

rm(dir: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Removes a file or directory

Where the second parameter is a boolean flag to set the recursitivity, so you just need to set it to true:

Comment: finally I use shutil.rmtree() to remove the folder. and create back using dbutils.fs.mkdirs

Comment: hi @mytabi , I encounter `No such file or directory` error when using `shutil.rmtree()`  instead of `dbutils.fs.rm()` on `wasbs://`-prefixed path, Could you describe how you did it on `wasbs://`-prefixed path? Thanks!